# Floyd Warshall: computing top-k shortest paths per vertex pair

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

In the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, the shortest path cost is computed for any pair of vertices. Additional book-keeping allows us to keep the actual path (list of vertices) on the shortest path.

How can I extend Floyd-Warshall so that for any pair of vertices, the top-K shortest paths are found? For example, for K=3, the result would be that the 3 shortest paths are computed and maintained?

I have been using the [Java implementation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/FloydWarshall.java.html) from Sedgewick.

Comment: Do you mean `K` different paths of same minimal length or `K` paths of different length, however being shorter than any other path?

Comment: The second one is what I meant.

Comment: I take back what I said earlier: Floyd--Warshall is not a suitable base on which to build this. The dynamic programming structure of F--W makes it more or less infeasible to detect duplicate paths efficiently.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Can you recommend a different algorithm as a base? I still want to solve all-pairs shortest path with top-k routes per pair of end points.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds more like Dijkstra would be simpler to modify for returning N shortest paths. The search is allowed to enter the vertex until K shortest alternatives has entered the vertex.

For more information you can check [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing)

Comment: Not sure if it is a requirement (question did not specify), but Dijkstra's algorithm can not handle negative edge weights.

Answer (score 0):

You may call the loop multiple times using an extra condition that could like

`for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
            // compute shortest paths using only 0, 1, ..., i as intermediate vertices
            for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
                if (edgeTo[v][i] == null) continue;  // optimization
                for (int w = 0; w < V; w++) {
                    if (distTo[v][w] > distTo[v][i] + distTo[i][w] && distTo[v][i]+distTo[i][w]>min[k]) { //min[k] is the minimum distance calculated in kth iteration of minimum distance calculation 
                        distTo[v][w] = distTo[v][i] + distTo[i][w];
                        edgeTo[v][w] = edgeTo[i][w];
                    }
                }
                // check for negative cycle
                if (distTo[v][v] < 0.0) {
                    hasNegativeCycle = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }`
This code will calculate the K minimum distances that are different. Hope it would help you.